# Is the cloudformation step necessary when we deploy the app to the aws lambda and if yes what are the exact permissions required under it

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

"arn:aws:iam::123456789:user/demo is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStacks on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-south-1:987654321:stack/demo-test-dev/* because no identity-based policy allows the cloudformation:DescribeStacks action."
when I try to upload the app it gives me this error so can somebody help me out of this.
Note: I have IAM user account with limited permissions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have enough permissions to be able to deploy the stack.

Yes, you need to have the permissions around CloudFormation.
And to deploy resources in it you will need to have those specific permissions too. see [documentation here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-errors-insufficient-iam-permissions).

Here the error tells you that you need to have `cloudformation:DescribeStacks` permissions to continue.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-south-1:987654321:stack/demo-test-dev/*",
        }
    ]
}
```